# When an inheritance turn into whole-part composition

Tags: oop, inheritance, containment

Here is the definition of whole-part composition.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition
And here is the inheritance.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29

I have encountered a question today and I can not solve. Assume that we have a software plan about a software that we are about to build. My question is, in which circumstances existing  inheritance relation between two class turn into composition? It sounds weird, but I can not answer it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composition (has-a) and Inheritance (is-a) are two distinctly different concepts. There is however a particular situation when the *is-a* turns into a *has-a*.  Consider

```
class MyItemList publicly inherits Vector<MyItem>...
```

This is a clear case of MyItemList *is-a* Vector. It has all the properties of a Vector, it can be used as a Vector of *MyItems* . Everybody can use an instance of MyItemList as a Vector.

Now consider

```
class MyItemList privately inherits Vector<MyItem>...
```

*MyItemList* is not telling anyone it is a *Vector*. Nobody can use MyItemList as a Vector. It has all the properties of a Vector (*has-a Vector*) but doesn't tell anyone about it.

This is effectively a *has-a* relationship. The only difference is MyItemList does not refer to the vector by an attribute/field/member, but rather by *this* (or whatever selfreferential keyword your language use).

*The language of your choice has to have a mechanism to declare inheritance as non-public of course.*